# Python3 PIL: Attempting to produce an image with (x,y,RGB) data

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a list of RGB values that I want to produce an image from, but I can't get past the first step of defining width and height for PIL without receiving ValueError: Size must be a tuple.
This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

width=73
height=880
img=Image.new(width,height,'RGB')
```

Comment: Do you know what a tuple is? Have you looked at [the documentation for `Image.new()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#constructing-images)?

Answer (score 0):

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

img=Image.new(mode,size,color)

size should be a tuple (width, height) in pixels ->

img=Image.new(mode,(width,height),color)